# how to do server side rendering in angular14

Tags: server-side-rendering, angular14

I am trying to do server-side-rendering in my angular application created in version 14.I tried the command "ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@14.1.0" at that time error occur. And the error is
"ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@14.1.0
Skipping installation: Package already installed
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"project":"FLYBUILDS","appId":"serverApp","main":"main.server.ts","appDir":"app","rootModuleFileName":"app.server.module.ts","rootModuleClassName":"AppServerModule","skipInstall":true}
Errors:

Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(appDir).
"
how to solve this error?

Answer (score -1):

If you're facing issues adding Angular Universal with Express Engine to an Angular 14 project, and encountering errors with the command:

```bash
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@14.1.0
```

**Solution:**
I encountered a similar problem, and here's how I resolved it:

1. **Compatibility Check:**
   Ensure that the versions of Angular Universal and Angular CLI are compatible with Angular 14
2. **Update Angular CLI:**
   Update your Angular CLI to the latest version using the following command:

   ```bash
   npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
   ```
3. **Use Latest Angular Universal:**
   Instead of specifying a version, try installing the latest version of Angular Universal:

   ```bash
   ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
   ```
4. **Clear npm Cache:**
   Clear the npm cache to prevent potential caching issues:

   ```bash
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
5. **Retry Installation:**
   After performing the above steps, try running the installation command again:

   ```bash
   ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: AI generated content is currently [banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned). Please read the AI Policy for more information:
[Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy):
Artificial Intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools may not be used to generate answers for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The answers you provide must either be your own original work, or the properly cited work of others. 
If your answers are determined to have been written by AI, they will likely be deleted, along with any reputation earned from them. 
Posting AI-generated content repeatedly may lead to a warning from moderators, or even a suspension from the site.